# Cassandra-Hector: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MEMTABLE_THROUGHPUT_IN_MB

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I'm trying to create a cassandra database but no matter what versions of cassandra and hector I use I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MEMTABLE_THROUGHPUT_IN_MB
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCfDef.<init>(ThriftCfDef.java:119) ~[hector-core-0.8.0-2.jar:?]
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCfDef.<init>(ThriftCfDef.java:125) ~[hector-core-0.8.0-2.jar:?]
at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(HFactory.java:679) ~[hector-core-0.8.0-2.jar:?]
at Databases.NoSQL.CassandraDB.AuthorsAndFeaturesCassandraSchema.writeAuthorsAndFeaturesPerKeywordToCassandraDB(AuthorsAndFeaturesCassandraSchema.java:87) ~[classes/:?]
```

Here's my code:

```
public class AuthorsAndFeaturesCassandraSchema {

public static StringSerializer stringSerializer=new StringSerializer();

public static String[] readAuthorsAndFeaturesPerKeywordFromCassandraDB(){
    CassandraHostConfigurator hostConfigurator=new CassandraHostConfigurator("localhost:9160");
    Cluster cluster= HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster","localhost:9160");

    KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDefinition=cluster.describeKeyspace("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace");

    if(cluster.describeKeyspace("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace")==null){
        ColumnFamilyDefinition columnFamilyDefinition=HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace","authorAndFeaturesKeyword", ComparatorType.BYTESTYPE);
        KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDefinition1=HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace", ThriftKsDef.DEF_STRATEGY_CLASS,1, Arrays.asList(columnFamilyDefinition));
        cluster.addKeyspace(keyspaceDefinition1,true);
    }

    ConfigurableConsistencyLevel configurableConsistencyLevel=new ConfigurableConsistencyLevel();
    Map<String,HConsistencyLevel> consistencyLevelMap=new HashMap<String, HConsistencyLevel>();
    consistencyLevelMap.put("AUTHOR_AND_FEATURES",HConsistencyLevel.ONE);
    configurableConsistencyLevel.setReadCfConsistencyLevels(consistencyLevelMap);
    configurableConsistencyLevel.setWriteCfConsistencyLevels(consistencyLevelMap);

    me.prettyprint.hector.api.Keyspace keyspace=HFactory.createKeyspace("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace",cluster,configurableConsistencyLevel);
    String[] serializedauthorsAndFeaturesHashmap=new String[3],authorsAndFeatures={"authorAndFeaturesKeyword-1","authorAndFeaturesKeyword-2","authorAndFeaturesKeyword-3"};
    try {
        ColumnQuery<String,String,String> columnQuery=HFactory.createStringColumnQuery(keyspace);
        for(int i=1;i<=authorsAndFeatures.length;i++){
            columnQuery.setColumnFamily("AUTHOR_AND_FEATURES").setKey("authorsAndFeaturesKeyword").setName(authorsAndFeatures[i]);
            QueryResult<HColumn<String,String>>result=columnQuery.execute();

            if(result==null){
                return  null;
            }

            HColumn<String,String>column=result.get();
            if(column==null){
                return  null;
            }
            serializedauthorsAndFeaturesHashmap[i]=column.getValue();
        }
    }catch (HectorException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return serializedauthorsAndFeaturesHashmap;
}


public static void writeAuthorsAndFeaturesPerKeywordToCassandraDB( String serializedAuthorsAndFeaturesPerKeywordHashmap,int index){
    CassandraHostConfigurator hostConfigurator=new CassandraHostConfigurator("localhost:9160");
    Cluster cluster=HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster","localhost:9160");

    ConfigurableConsistencyLevel configurableConsistencyLevel=new ConfigurableConsistencyLevel();
    Map<String,HConsistencyLevel>consistencyLevelMap=new HashMap<String, HConsistencyLevel>();
    consistencyLevelMap.put("AUTHOR_AND_FEATURES",HConsistencyLevel.ONE);
    configurableConsistencyLevel.setReadCfConsistencyLevels(consistencyLevelMap);
    configurableConsistencyLevel.setWriteCfConsistencyLevels(consistencyLevelMap);

    KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDefinition=cluster.describeKeyspace("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace");
    if(cluster.describeKeyspace("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace")==null){
        ColumnFamilyDefinition columnFamilyDefinition=HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace","authorAndFeaturesKeyword",ComparatorType.BYTESTYPE);
        KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDefinition1=HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace",ThriftKsDef.DEF_STRATEGY_CLASS,1,Arrays.asList(columnFamilyDefinition));
        cluster.addKeyspace(keyspaceDefinition1,true);
    }
    me.prettyprint.hector.api.Keyspace keyspace=HFactory.createKeyspace("authorAndFeaturesKeyspace",cluster,configurableConsistencyLevel);
    Mutator<String>mutator=HFactory.createMutator(keyspace,StringSerializer.get());
    try {
        mutator.insert("authorAndFeaturesKeyword","AUTHOR_AND_FEATURES",HFactory.createStringColumn("authorAndFeaturesKeyword-"+index,serializedAuthorsAndFeaturesPerKeywordHashmap));
    }catch (HectorException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

I'm currently using hector's 0.8.0-2 and cassandra's 1.2.5 version

Thanks in advance

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason for writing anything in Hector, as it has long since been deprecated.  The Hector project on GitHub hasn't had a commit in almost 2 years, and its readme even says that it should no longer be used.  Your highest chances for success will be to use Cassandra 2.1.14 with the DataStax Java driver.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening most likely because you're using incompatible versions of Hector and Cassandra.  You should use Hector **1.0-5** with Cassandra 1.2.5.